# How to read excel file where office is not installed(C#3.0, dotnet 3.5)

Tags: excel, c#-3.0

Hi I am facing a problem.

In my server, there is no office installed. However, I need to access data from excel file.

I used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll file. I am under the impression that this will work

because the dll location is

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll
```

The same is available in the server machine also. But it does not have office installed there

But when I ran the program I got the exception

```
System Exception:System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
```

Googling does not provide much support.

Also, it is very urgent.

Kindly help.

Comment: "[URGENT]" adds _nothing_ useful to your question. In fact, it makes me read _slower_. Lack of planning on your part does not constitute an emergency on our part :-)

Comment: Removed the stupid urgent part, else you will surely get no answers fast.

Comment: pls send me the codes, is urgent

Comment: If you just need data, you can get it from Excel with Jet connection.

Answer (score 2):

The Office PI assemblies simply wrap the Office COM components to provide an interface that can be called from .NET managed code. You still need Office installed, however, you have other options...

If you are working with Office 2007 files, you could try the [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en).

Alternatively, if you are working with files form an earlier version of Office there are third party libraries available, e.g. [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Excel & C#, try http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Free library that can read/write spreadsheets, very very easy to use with Excel.

Example of reading in Excel files as demanded by OP:

```
FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(FilePath);
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
{
    // get the first worksheet in the workbook
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    int col = 2; //The item description
    // output the data in column 2
    for (int row = 2; row < 5; row++)
        Console.WriteLine("\tCell({0},{1}).Value={2}", row, col, worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value);

    // output the formula in row 5
    Console.WriteLine("\tCell({0},{1}).Formula={2}", 3, 5, worksheet.Cells[3, 5].Formula);                
    Console.WriteLine("\tCell({0},{1}).FormulaR1C1={2}", 3, 5, worksheet.Cells[3, 5].FormulaR1C1);

} // the using statement automatically calls Dispose() which closes the package.
```

PS: Asking with please/thanks will likely get more people to help ;)

Comment: http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/59882#885360

Look at sample2.cs in the source code repository.

Answer (score 1):

You're stuffed basically.  The interop file simply points to a COM object which is registered by Excel when it is installed.

Since you don't have Excel, its COM registration won't be in the registry so the interop file is effectively pointing at a broken link hence you get the COMException.

You'll need to install Office to make this works as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) may do the work (it does not requires office to be installed).